Best optotriac/phototriac for switching an inductor out of a circuit
I have the circuit below where I'm using a full bridge driver to drive an LC circuit (L1 and C1). I want to switch another inductor (L2) in and out of this circuit to alter the resonant frequency, on the fly. This is operating at around 150kHz.
Without L2 and the optotriac in the circuit I get around 350V (at approx 5mA) at point A. With both in the circuit and the optotriac ON, I only get about 250V at A.
Ideally I would like to get as close to the original 350V as possible. So my questions are:

Is this possible with this circuit?
If so, what optotriac should I use and/or what parameter of the triac should I be focusing on for this application?
If not, are there any suggestions of an alternate circuit?

Thanks in advance.


What are the component values here? Have you checked the dV/dt rating on the TRIAC? Off-state capacitance?

@TimWilliams my understanding is that the dV/dt relates to how quickly the triac will turn on, or off. In this case the triac is turned on and left on for quite some time (around 100ms). The input to output capacitance is 0.8pF which will have limited impact as C1 is around 5.6nF

No, in fact there is a critical dV/dt above which, when applied to a nonconducting TRIAC, the TRIAC itself will turn on. This is a big concern in high frequency use. The turn-off time (t_q) likewise is important to turn-off. || Regarding capacitance, I didn't say isolation, I say off-state, i.e. C(MT1, MT2). What is it specified as, and how will that affect your circuit? If not specified -- could any value affect your circuit?

According to the datasheet, the dV/dt is 500V/us and the dV/dt(c) is 0.2V/us. I can't find  C(MT1, MT2) in the datasheet. Note that I don't have an issue with the frequency changing (from additional capacitance) when on, I have an issue with reduced amplitude.
